# Why $v_1 \in L$ and $v_2 \in L^\perp$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $L$ be a one dimensional subspace of $R^2$ (we may view $L$ as a line in the plane through the origin).
Suppose $\alpha$ is the angle from the positive x axis to $L$.
Let $v_1=(\cos \alpha, \sin \alpha)$ and $v_2=(-\sin \alpha, \cos \alpha)$.
Then $v_1 \in L$ and $v_2 \in L^\perp$.
I can't understand the last line. Why $v_1 \in L$ and $v_2 \in L^\perp$?

Comment: Draw a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector $ \ \overrightarrow{v_1} \ $ is a *unit* vector which lies in the line L , so it would be considered an element of the vector subspace $ \ L \ $ , which is the set of all vectors pointing along the line L (in either direction).  Since $ \ \overrightarrow{v_1}  \cdot   \overrightarrow{v_2} \ = \ 0 $ , the second vector is perpendicular to the first, and so must lie in the vector subspace in $ \ \mathbb{R}^2  $ which is designated as $ \ L^{\bot} \ $ ; it is *also* a unit vector, so   $ \ \overrightarrow{v_2} \ $ would be one element of  $ \ L^{\bot} \  . $

Comment: I like this elegant way of showing that it must be true, but to understand why it is from the other side, one can remember the form of a 2D rotation matrix: $R = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos \alpha & -\sin \alpha \\
\sin \alpha & \cos \alpha \\
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Actually, I thought OP's question was more concerned with why the vectors are described as _elements_ of the indicated subspaces.  (But I figured I'd cover the orthogonality matter at the same time.)

Comment: You're absolutely correct, I just thought the rotation matrix was another route to understanding the answer.

Comment: It can be indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to visualizing it is noting that $$\cos(a+\frac{\pi}{2}) = -\sin(a)$$ and $$\sin(a+\frac{\pi}{2}) = \cos(a)$$ so basically you are rotating the vector by $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: Both identities have a sign error.

Comment: thank you, just misread my own writing and did't see the error :(

Answer (score 0):

Since $L$ is a line going through $(0,0)$ you can write 
$$
  L
= \{ t \vec{d}: t \in \mathbb{R} \}
$$
for some unit vector $\vec{d} = (x,y)$. Since $\alpha$ is the angle it makes with the positive $x$-axis, drawing yourself a right triangle whose vertices are $(0,0)$, $(x,y)$ and $(x,0)$, you see that $\cos\alpha = x/1=x$ and $\sin\alpha = y/1=y$, (the fact that $\vec{d}$ is a unit vector means the hypotenuse of the triangle here is $1$).

That is to say $v_1 = (\cos\alpha,\sin\alpha) = (x,y) = \vec{d}$, so $L$ is just the span of $v_1$. This explains the first part of the statement.

The second part says that, for any element $w \in L$, $v_2 \cdot w = 0$. You can check this by noting that any $w \in L$ has the form $w = tv_1$ for some $t \in \mathbb{R}$ by the first statement, and so 
$$
  v_2 \cdot w
= t (-\sin\alpha, \cos\alpha) \cdot (\cos\alpha,\sin\alpha)
= t (-\sin\alpha\cos\alpha + \cos\alpha\sin\alpha)
= 0.
$$